# set an annotation attribute from an environment variable?

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I'm trying to set an annotation value from an environment variable:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
class Application {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${DB_CRON}")
    def void schedule() {
       ...
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application, args)
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I get the following compile time error:

> Attribute 'cron' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 
>   'java.lang.Object' in
>   @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

Is it possible to set the annotation this way, or do I need to use some other technique such as setting the value in a property file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use GStrings in java annotations in groovy.  You have to use "proper" Strings.  E.g.

```
@Scheduled(cron = '${DB_CRON}')
```

Note the **single quotes** here.  If groovy sees a `$` in `"`-quoted string, it will turn it into a GString.  This can not be done with java annotations and you actually don't want to do it here anyway, since you want your spring property be set here.  This also is, what the error message tries to say here, that no basetype string is used here but some object (the GString).

Comment: This is closer to a working solution, but I now hit a runtime error: `Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setSystemPropertiesMode() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]
Possible solutions: setSystemPropertiesMode(int), setSystemPropertiesModeName(java.lang.String)`.  **Note:** `snowch$ echo "$db_cron"` -> `0 19 21 * * *`

Comment: please edit the question, provide the full error message with trace and correlate line numbers from your code

Comment: There was some other code that was throwing this error.  I've removed that code and all is working now.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "#{systemEnvironment['ANDROID_HOME']}")
 def void schedule() {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, you have got me one step closer but I'm now receiving another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834309/cron-expression-must-consist-of-6-fields-found-1-in

Comment: I will appreciate if you mark this question as "answered"

Comment: The quality of this answer could be improved by adding some additional explanation as to why this solution is supposed to solve the problem.