# Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "#{systemEnvironment['db_cron']}")

Tags: spring, groovy, cron, spring-el

I'm trying to set a cron Scheduled annotation as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{systemEnvironment['db_cron']}")
def void schedule() {

}
```

Next set the environment variable as:

```
export db_cron="0 19 21 * * *"
```

However, I get the runtime error:

```
Cron expression must consist of 6 fields 
  (found 1 in "#{systemEnvironment['db_cron']}")
```

What can be going wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I have also tried: `@Scheduled(cron = "${db_cron}")`

But this returns a **compile** time error:

```
/Users/snowch/repos/sales/Prospects/Snow/Plugwise/etl_service/src/main/groovy/com/ibm/etl/Application.groovy: 52: Expected '$db_cron' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String in @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
 @ line 52, column 23.
       @Scheduled(cron = "${db_cron}")
                         ^

/Users/snowch/repos/sales/Prospects/Snow/Plugwise/etl_service/src/main/groovy/com/ibm/etl/Application.groovy: -1: Attribute 'cron' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
 @ line -1, column -1.
2 errors

:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have tried `@Scheduled(cron = "#{db_cron}")`

But the **runtime** error was:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setSystemPropertiesMode() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]
Possible solutions: setSystemPropertiesMode(int), setSystemPropertiesModeName(java.lang.String)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1373)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1359)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.ibm.etl.Application.main(Application.groovy:43)
```

Note the environment variable is set as follows:

```
snowch$ echo "$db_cron"
0 19 21 * * *
```

Comment: I guess the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832972/set-an-annotation-attribute-from-an-environment-variable was wrong :-\

Comment: you can not use GStrings ("${}") in an annotation.  use '${}' (single quotes) there.

Comment: Using single strings results in the error: `Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setSystemPropertiesMode() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set env variable like you do:

```
export db_cron="0 19 21 * * *"
```

then restart your ide if you are using or restart your terminal session.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${db_cron}")
def void schedule() {
   ...
}
```

I tried it and here is my screenshot. Everything works as expected...[image: cron expression as env variable]

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work: `Attribute 'cron' should have type 'java.lang.String'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled`

Comment: @ChrisSnow i guess `"#{db_cron}"` or `'${db_cron}'` could fix this

Comment: the .*rc part it not relevant.  it is only important, that the environment variable is set before the application is run and that the app is run in that same "session" where the var is set (don't set it in your shell and expect it to be there in your intellij)

Comment: @cfrick is right. logging out and setting env var in .bashrc or .zshrc is useless.

Comment: I've updated the question with the result of trying `"#{db_cron}"` and `"${db_cron}"`

Comment: this is very strange. i'm not familiar with groovy but i can't find the difference. In java everything works as expected may be is something related to groovy?

Comment: The problem was due to the GStrings.  Changing `"${db_cron}"` to `'${db_cron}'` fixed the issue.

Comment: I have property in .yml file and cron job is not considering as String

Answer (score 0):

For me worked using JDK 11 and Spring 2.3.3 adding double quotes both the variables:

```
export db_cron="0 19 21 * * *"
```

and:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${db_cron}")
```

**Note:** works in application.properties files too.